# 404 page not found rancher and k3s, how to resolve?

Tags: k3s, rancher

## Step 1

Download k3s

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_VERSION=v1.26.11+k3s1 sh -s - server --write-kubeconfig-mode 666
```

## Step 2

Install cert manager.

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.13.3/cert-manager.crds.yaml
```

## Step 3

Install docker

```
sudo dnf config-manager --add-repo=https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
sudo dnf install -y docker-ce
sudo dnf install -y docker-ce-cli containerd.io
sudo systemctl start docker && sudo systemctl enable docker && sudo systemctl status docker
```

## Step 4

Install rancher

```
docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped \
  -p 80:80 -p 443:443 \
  --privileged \
  rancher/rancher:latest
```

## Step 5

```
reboot
```

These are my SSH tunnel to access rancher web portal. My VM is natted at port 3232(Guest IP=10.0.2.15 Guest port=22)(Host IP=127.0.0.1 Host Port=3232)

[SSH tunnel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu1LT.png)

Still I’m unable to access the web portal from https://localhost:9487, I get 404 page not found.